# Bootstrap Tooltip-Popover v2.2.2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hover, tooltip, popover

I am having a problem with using bootstrap v 2.2.2 and tooltip-popover functions.

The effect I wish to achieve is for a popup to appear when the box is hovered over as show in the link below.

http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/popover-example.html

The problem is that the code provided does not seem to work with v2.2.2. I believe the problem maybe that in the latest version these files

```
<script src="js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>  
<script src="js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
```

Do not exist. I have read the documentation and almost every other thread and tutorial however I cannot seem to work out how to make it work.

Any help would be greatful

Answer (score 0):

```
<a data-placement="right" data-trigger="hover"  rel="popover"  data-content="It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!" data-original-title="Tooltip on right" href="#">Popover</a>

$(function () {

$('a[rel=popover]').popover();

})

This should display the popover on the right side.
```